# Why does one user only see my site correctly when using a VPN?

Tags: javascript, vpn

When a particular user tries to visit my site there's a problem with some of my JS not getting executed. But, when my client uses a VPN, the JS gets executed.

It seems very peculiar to me, because the website works just fine for everyone else. Does anyone have any ideas about what could be causing this or what the solution is?

Comment: Do some scripts just fail to load that are only accessible through the VPN?

Answer (score 0):

If you use remote js library and if that user does not have access to that domain/ip and if he has access through VPN, that is possible.

That's just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your user to run in Firefox with Firebug, or Chrome with developer tools, without VPN, and report what's shown in the console tab.  (If you're familiar with the debugging tools in IE, that's also an option.)

Edited to add: And if the solution isn't luminously clear from the information in the console tab, please come back and update your question with that information.  I'll try to help.